# Close Epic when all stories transition are Done

Tags: groovy, jira

I would like to Automatically close the Epic when all linked stories and Tasks are on status "Done". I am not good with groovy, still fresh and trying trying to find my feet. So I have the following script:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.customisers.ContextBaseScript
import groovy.transform.BaseScript
import org.apache.log4j.Logger

@BaseScript ContextBaseScript context

def issueLinkManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueLinkManager()
def issueService = ComponentAccessor.getIssueService()

def currentUser = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext.getLoggedInUser()

def isEpicInProgress = {Issue epic ->
    if (epic.issueType.name == "Epic") {
        if (epic.statusObject.name != "Done") {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

def isStoryClosed = {Issue story ->
    if (story.statusObject.name == "Done") {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

def updateEpic = {Issue epic ->
    if (isEpicInProgress) {
        def parameters = issueService.newIssueInputParameters()
        def result = issueService.validateTransition(currentUser, epic.id, 31, parameters)
        issueService.transition(currentUser, result)
        log.warn("Epic update to " + result)
    }
}

def isEpicClosable = {Issue epic ->
    def finalResult = true

    issueLinkManager.getOutwardLinks(epic.id).each { link ->
        def story = link.destinationObject
        def closedStory = isStoryClosed(story)
        finalResult = closedStory && finalResult
    }
    log.warn("Final result is " + finalResult);
    return finalResult
}

issueLinkManager.getInwardLinks(issue.id).each { link ->
    def linkTypeId = link.getLinkTypeId()
    def isEpicOfLinkType = 10300
    if (isEpicOfLinkType == linkTypeId) {
        def epic = link.sourceObject
        if (isEpicInProgress(epic)) {
            if (isEpicClosable(epic)) {
                updateEpic(epic)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JIRA is complaining about the following:

> story.statusObject.name is deprecated -> I don't know how to find the the new one

The second problem I'm getting is that except the above warning, the script runs without producing any errors, but the Epic fails to transition automatically.[image] 
Above is the workflow for Story Issue Type
[image]
Above is the Epic Issue Type.

Please assist :)

Answer (score 0):

[For your warning](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/server/com/atlassian/jira/issue/Issue.html#getStatusObject--):
Instead of *getStatusObject()*, use *getStatus()*. It does the same thing, but is not deprecated.

In *updateEpic()* you have:

```
def result = issueService.validateTransition(currentUser, epic.id, 31, parameters)
issueService.transition(currentUser, result)
```

Your result variable is an instance of *[TransitionValidationResult](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/7.0.3/com/atlassian/jira/bc/issue/IssueService.TransitionValidationResult.html)* which implements *[ServiceResult](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/server/com/atlassian/jira/bc/ServiceResult.html)*. It contains collections of warnings and errors. You should check/log those to figure out what exactly goes wrong with your transition. To simply check if your transition will succeed, use `result.isValid()`